# Python. Telegram bot. Не работает кнопка

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Пытаюсь реализовать механизм реакции бота на нажатие кнопки. К сожалению, бот не выдает ожидаемый результат. В чем ошибка?

```
import logging

from telegram import KeyboardButton, ReplyKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler

logging.basicConfig(
    format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

start_button = 'Начать'
start_text = '''
Для старта, нажмите "Начать" \U0001F447
    '''

def start(update, _):
    keyboard = [
        [
            KeyboardButton(start_button, callback_data='1'),
        ],
    ]
    reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(keyboard, resize_keyboard=True)
    update.message.reply_text(start_text, reply_markup=reply_markup)


def button(update, _):
    query = update.callback_query
    variant = query.data
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text(text=f"Нажата кнопка: {variant}")

def help_command(update, _):
    update.message.reply_text("Используйте `/start` для запуска бота.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    updater = Updater("TOKEN")

    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(button))
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('help', help_command))

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Comment: почему у вас keyboard расположен в списке, который расположен в списке? так и нужно?

Comment: Насколько мне известно, да. Первый список в списке - горизонтальный кнопки, второй (если бы он был) - вертикальные.